# JSON, Serialize или что это?

Tags: json, serialize, php, javascript

Скажите пожалуйста, этот код JSON, SERIALIZE, или как составлен? Могу я все данные из этого кода сделать массивом PHP?

```
"thumbnail_url":"http://___________/events/000000000028437f/169a7507-52f7-4148-8d27-66f158d43bf8_4140.jpg","thumbnail_url_small":"http://___________/events/000000000028437f/169a7507-52f7-4148-8d27-66f158d43bf8_4140_150x84.jpg","progressive_url":"http://____________/events/000000000028437f/169a7507-52f7-4148-8d27-66f158d43bf8_756.mp4?__gda__=1388134903_f3d8589a159ab4edbf36d379f926b7ca"}},{"type":"video","data":{"id":38105981,"event_id":2638719,"caption":"English - 18 Great Stages of the Path (Lam Rim) Commentaries - Session 3",
```

Если нет, то как можно регуляркой вытянуть данные thumbnail_url, caption, progressive_url??? Как это сделать?
Спасибо

**UPDATE** Добавил код более полный http://pastebin.com/M0rYHXEM

Comment: Это какие-то обрывки JSON, а так:
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Спасибо ребят, благодаря вам, написал полезный сервис - http://casecode.ru/livestream.php

Comment: чуть не в тему, но при пустом запросы вылазит `Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: Filename cannot be empty in /var/www/admin/data/www/casecode.ru/livestream.php on line 70`

Также сделайте проверку регуляркой на соответствие ссылки, закинул `http://vod1.livestream.com/events/0000000000280c3f/dd4f4c4f-9e87-4980-8f75-16cac2a33c28_678.mp4` и сайт пошел качать ее походу, вам так сайт положат за пару секунд

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас какой-то битый JSON, если его структуру восстановить, то очень просто можно получить все необходимые данные.

Код на [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/mrjqOB)

Comment: @ua6xh добавил полный код, к сожалению при попытке его декодировать json вылезает null

Comment: @chuikoff - такие большие фрагменты лучше выкладывать на pastebin.com

Comment: @ua6xh http://pastebin.com/M0rYHXEM

Comment: @chuikoff - у вас в самом конце стоит символ ";"

Используйте так же [jsoneditoronline.org][1] для проверки валидности JSON

[1]: http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался)

Answer (score 0):

Вы бы еще менее информативный кусок выдернули ))).Но судя по  {} это JSON, и тогда

```
print_r(json_decode($data, true));
```

и смотрите структуру и идите по дереву

Comment: @aldem67 а теперь достаточно кода для анализа?)

Comment: json_deco*d*e

Comment: Спасибо, подправил опечатку.